# ARM ASSEMBLY loop through argv arguments

Tags: loops, assembly, arm, argv

I am trying to pass arguments to my program at the command line using argv, i figured out how to point to the first argv address, but i cannot seem to loop to the next one.

here is my code, but I think that what is relevant is in the first subroutine:

```
 .text
         .global _start
         .equ exit, 1
         .equ write, 4
         .equ stdout, 1

 _start:
    ldr r5, [sp]        @argc value
    ldr r6, =1
    mov r8, #8          @argv address

 0: ldr r4, [sp, r8]        
    add r8, r8, #4   
    mov r1, r4
    adr r10, isbn10 
    adr r11, valid
    adr r12, invalid
    adr r13, isbn13
    bl strlen
    cmp r0, #13
    beq 1f
    cmp r0, #10
    beq 2f

1:  bl check_13
    cmp r2,#0
    bleq print13v
    blne print13i
    add r6, r6, #1 
    cmp r5,r6
    bne 0b
    mov r0, #0      @ success exit code
    mov r7, #exit
    svc 0   

2:  bl check_10
    cmp r2,#0
    bleq print10v
    blne print10i
    add r6, r6, #1 
    cmp r5,r6
    bne 0b
    mov r0, #0      @ success exit code
    mov r7, #exit
    svc 0           @ return to os

val:.asciz "9780306406157"
isbn10:.asciz "\nisbn-10 : "
isbn13:.asciz "\nisbn-13 : "
valid:.asciz ": valid"  
invalid:.asciz ": invalid"
.align 2

strlen:


    mov r0, #0
            @ length to return
0:
    ldrb r2, [r1], #1   @ get current char and advance
    cmp r2, #0      @ are we at the end of the string?
    addne r0, #1
    bne 0b
    mov pc, lr  

#######################


check_13:       @sum at r2
    mov r1, r4
    mov r3,#1       @toggle
    mov r2,#0       @sum
0:  
    ldrb r0,[r1], #1
    cmp r0, #0
    beq 9f
    cmp r0, #'0
    blo 1f
    cmp r0, #'9
    bhi 1f
    sub r0,r0,#'0
    add r2,r2,r0
    cmp r2, #10
    subge r2,r2,#10
    eors r3,r3,#1       @toggled?
    addne r2,r2,r0,lsl#1
    cmp r2, #10
    subge r2,r2,#10
    cmp r2, #10
    subge r2,r2,#10
    bal 0b




1:  mov r2, #22     @returns r2=22 if invalid
    mov pc,lr

9:  mov pc,lr

##################



check_10:       @sum at r2
    mov r1, r4
    mov r3,#0       @t
    mov r2,#0       @sum
0:  
    ldrb r0,[r1], #1
    cmp r0, #0      @end?
    beq 9f
    cmp r0, #'0
    blo 1f
    cmp r0, #'9
    bhi 2f
    sub r0,r0,#'0
    bal 3f

3:  add r3,r3,r0
    cmp r3, #11
    subge r3, r3, #11
    add r2,r2,r3
    cmp r2, #11
    subge r2, r2, #11       
    bal 0b



2:  and r0,r0, #0xdf    @ x becomes x
    cmp r0, #0x58       @ x?
    bne 1f
    mov r0,#10
    bal 3b

1:  mov r2, #22     @returns r2=22 if invalid
    mov pc,lr

9:  mov pc,lr

######################
invalid:
    mov r2, #22     @returns r2=22 if invalid
    mov pc,lr
#######################
print10v:
    mov r9,lr
    mov r1,r10
    bl strlen 
    mov r2,r0
    mov r1,r10  
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write @herehere
    svc 0

    mov r1,r4
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r4
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0

    mov r1,r11
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r11
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov pc,r9

#######################
print10i:
    mov r9,lr
    mov r1,r10
    bl strlen 
    mov r2,r0
    mov r1,r10  
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write @herehere
    svc 0

    mov r1,r4
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r4
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0

    mov r1,r12
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r12
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov pc,r9

#######################
print13v:
    mov r9,lr
    mov r1,r13
    bl strlen 
    mov r2,r0
    mov r1,r13  
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write @herehere
    svc 0

    mov r1,r4
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r4
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0

    mov r1,r11
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r11
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov pc,r9

#######################
print13i:
    mov r9,lr
    mov r1,r13
    bl strlen 
    mov r2,r0
    mov r1,r13  
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write @herehere
    svc 0

    mov r1,r4
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r4
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0

    mov r1,r12
    bl strlen
    mov r1,r12
    mov r2,r0
    mov r0,#stdout
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov pc,r9
```

after i assemble and link it 
i run it using ./validate 9780306406157 1234567890
ISBN-13 : 9780306406157: VALID
ISBN-13 : 306406157: INVALID[Inferior 1 (process 22221) exited normally]

meaning that r4 at the second time through the loop got 306406157, i wanted it to get 1234567890...

after doing the suggested editing i ran the program and it gave me a segmentation on line 60, when i try to read a byte (a char) from the new argument, i ran gdb and i noticed that the value of `r4` (supposed to be `argv[2]` on the second time through the loop) is very far from the value in the first time through the loop

```
14              mov r1, r4
(gdb) i r
r0             0x0      0
r1             0x0      0
r2             0x0      0
r3             0x0      0
r4             0xbefff8d6       3204446422
r5             0x3      3
r6             0x1      1
r7             0x0      0
r8             0xc      12
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbefff790       0xbefff790
lr             0x0      0
pc             0x8068   0x8068 <_start+20>
cpsr           0x10     16
(gdb) c
Continuing.

isbn-13 : 9780306406157: valid
Breakpoint 1, _start () at validate.s:12
12      0:      ldr r4, [sp, r8]
(gdb) stepi
13              add r8, r8, #4
(gdb)
14              mov r1, r4
(gdb) i r
r0             0x7      7
r1             0x8106   33030
r2             0x7      7
r3             0x0      0
r4             0x6176203a       1635131450
r5             0x3      3
r6             0x2      2
r7             0x4      4
r8             0x10     16
r9             0x809c   32924
r10            0x80ee   33006
r11            0x8106   33030
r12            0x81f4   33268
sp             0x80fa   0x80fa
lr             0x82f8   33528
pc             0x8068   0x8068 <_start+20>
cpsr           0x20000010       536870928
```

any help?

Comment: the code is big, clustered and i dont respect the caller protocol (not using r4....r13), i am sorry. This is my first program ....

Answer (score 1):

What you get when you do `ldr r4, [sp, #8]` is `argv[1]` (`argv[0]` which is at `[sp, #4]` is the name of the executing program).

So `addne r4, r4, #4` will just move 4 bytes ahead within `argv[1]`. What you should do to load `argv[2]`, `argv[3]`, etc., is to read from `[sp, #0xC]`, `[sp, #0x10]`, etc.

Something like this:

```
    mov r8, #8              @ Offset of argv[1]

0:  ldr r4, [sp, r8]        r4 = argv[n]
    add r8, r8, #4          n++
    mov r1, r4
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and it gave me a segmentation fault, maybe i should do the ldr r4, [sp, r8] before the 0: ?

Comment: You need one `ldr` for every element of `argv` that you want to load, so it should be in the loop. Where exactly does it crash? Run the program in a debugger and check the register values at the point of the crash.

Comment: From your gdb output it's apparent that `sp` is changing, though it's not apparent from your code what's changing it. Is it possible to do `watch sp` in gdb?

Comment: That was a question. I don't know whether it's possible. Alternatively you could step through every instruction and print the registers after each one until you find where `sp` changes.

Comment: sp changes when i call strlen, the first time in my loop at line 19 and doesnt change until the end, even when i call strlen on the second loop

Comment: Oh, heh, that's because you do `adr r13, isbn13`. `r13` is `sp`. Don't use `r13/sp` as a general-purpose register.